# Collections.sort() error

Tags: java, compareto

I am trying to sort a list of type A named BinOrder in class B according to Class A's int r.

However i am receiving this error for the line Collections.sort(BinOrder);

```
The method sort(List<T>) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList<A>)
```

Class A:

```
public class A{
int s; 
int r;

public A(int si, int ri) {
    s=si;
    r= ri;
 }
}
```

Class B:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;


public class B implements Comparable<A> {



    public Iterator<A> randomMethodName(int a) {
        ArrayList<A> BinOrder = new ArrayList<A>();
                A a = new A(1,3)
                A a2 = new A(1,4)

                BinOrder.add(a);
                BinOrder.add(a2);
        }

        // sort array in increasing order of r
        Collections.sort(BinOrder);
        return BinOrder;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(A list) {

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your A is not comparable.

Comment: There are so many compiler errors in your sample. Please correct it.

Comment: How do you expect your `compareTo` method to compile? `null` isn't convertible to `int`...

Comment: I thought that comparable needed to be implemented wherever the compareTo() method is?

@JonSkeet, this is not a compile error, it's an ... IDE error? When i hover over Collections.sort(); it pops up the error.

Comment: @user2369869: Your code has multiple problems. You need to implement `compareTo` if you're going to implement `Comparable`, but you *don't* implement it by returning null...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To be able to use the single-argument version of [`Collection.sort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List)) on an `ArrayList` of `A`, `A` should implement the `Comparable` interface:

```
public class A implements Comparable<A> {
  ...
  @Override
  int compareTo(A rhs) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: So class A, and not class B, should be the one to have a compareTo() method and implement the interface Comparable?

Comment: @user2369869: Yes. You are sorting instances of `A`, so that's what you need to be able to compare. For this, `B` is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the signature of Collections.sort :

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(List<T> list)
```

`A` must implement Comparable for this method.

You try to pass `BinOrder` to this method, when `BinOrder` is of type `ArrayList<A>`, but since `A` does not implement `Comparable<A>`, it doesn't fit the signature of the method.

Either change `A` to implement Comparable, or use the `sort` method that accepts a Comparator :

```
public static <T> void sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c)
```

Comment: I thought that comparable needed to be implemented wherever the compareTo() method is?

Comment: @user2369869 compareTo is the method you have to implement for the Comparable interface, so it's the other way around.